# Extending LCA solution from tree to DAGs

Tags: algorithm, tree, directed-acyclic-graphs, rmq, lowest-common-ancestor

I'm using the algorithm that solves LCA in a tree using RMQ.

It basically works like this:

[image: Simple Tree]

- We perform an Euler tour on the tree, getting 3 arrays

  ```
  E = {0,1,0,2,0} //the vertexes in the order they were visited
  L = {0,1,0,1,0} //the levels of each of these vertexes
  I = {0,1,3}     //index of the first ocurrence of each vertex
  ```
- If we want the `LCA(u,v)`, we just need to get the RMQ of `L` from `I[u]` to `I[v]`.

> example: LCA(1,2) = RMQ of L from index `I[1] = 1` to `I[2] = 3`.
>
> L[1:3] = [1,0,1], RMQ[1,0,1] = 0, which is index 2, so the **LCA(1,2) = E[2] = 0**.

---

My question is: **how do I extend this solution to fit a Directed Acyclic Graph**?

The way it is, it doesn't work. Suppose we have this DAG:

[image: Directed Acyclic Graph]

If we compute `E`, `L` and `I`, we'll have:

```
E = {0,1,3,1,4,1,0,2,4,2,5,2,0}
L = {0,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,2,1,0}
I = {0,1,7,2,4,10}
```

And the proof it is wrong can be seen calculating LCA(2,4), which should obviously be 2, since 2 is 4's parent, but following the algorithm, we would compute:

> RMQ( I[2] : I[4] ) = RMQ(7,4) = RMQ(4,7) = RMQ( {2,1,0,1} ) = 0
>
> 0 has index 6, so **LCA(2,4) = E[6] = 0**, which is **wrong**.

Is there a way to make it work?